# Do functions with composition form a ring?

Tags: functions, ring-theory, universal-algebra

Functions with composition form a monoid, and injective functions with composition form a group. Is there in some sense a natural or useful definition for "addition" that would enable formation of a ring? If not, is there a sensible subset of functions where this is possible?

Comment: Perhaps you mean functions $f:X\to X$, where $X$ is a finite set. Otherwise, injective functions don't necessarily form a group. For example, $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that $f(n)=n+1$ doesn't have an inverse.

Comment: @amrsa I don't think I understand; isn't the inverse of $f(n)=n+1$ $f(n)=n-1$?

Comment: @IllidanS4wantsMonicaback that sends $0$ to $-1$ which isn’t in the set.  The point is you need to send everything back one as you said, but then there’s nowhere left to send $0$.

Comment: Initially because of the title I thought it was a duplicate, but rereading I see you’re looking for an addition. That’s probably new...

Comment: @rschwieb Ah, I get it now. I was thinking in terms of functions on $ℝ$.

Comment: @IllidanS4wantsMonicaback Again, functions on $\mathbb R$ have the same problem. For example, if $f(x)=e^x$, then $f$ is injective but not surjective; thus it doesn't have an inverse. Again, you could argue that it has the inverse $f^{-1}(x)=\log x$, but that's not a function on $\mathbb R$, since the domain of the logarithm is $\mathbb R^+$. In general, what you have is that bijective functions $f:X\to X$ form a group, whatever $X$; if $X$ is finite, then it is enough that $f$ is injective (or surjective), as it will follow that it is bijective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $X$ is a set with more than one element and $M$ is the set of functions $X\to X$, then there is no addition operation on $M$ that makes $M$ a ring where composition is multiplication.  Indeed, if there were such an operation, then the $0$ element of $M$ would need to satisfy $0f=f0=0$ for all $f\in M$.  But there is no such function $0$.  For instance, pick some $x\in X$ and pick some $y\in X$ which is different from $0(x)$ (we can do this since $X$ has more than one element).  Let $f$ be the constant function with value $y$.  Then $f0(x)=y\neq 0(x)$ so $f0\neq 0$.

One variant where you can get a nice ring structure is when $X$ itself has an abelian group structure, and you restrict $M$ to consist of only the group homomorphisms $X\to X$.  Then you can define an addition on $M$ by pointwise addition ($(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ where on the right side we use the group operation of $X$)), and this will make $M$ a ring with composition as multiplication, called the *endomorphism ring of $X$*.